# google appspot alternatives

Tags: google-app-engine, real-time, collaboration

is there any alternatives for google appspot engine?
I tried google appspot but it turns out very expensive and was wondering if I could install the daemon on my server (vps) but it will need to be similar to google appspot. any ideas

Comment: Have you investigated what's expensive about Google App Engine?  Usually there are many things you can do to reduce cost.  Or is the baseline $9/month already too much for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are some projects that are (nearly) API-compatible with GAE: [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/)(Java/Python), [TyphooneAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) (Python)

Comment: Do you know if there's any production environment that really use those two projects? I am under the impression that both AppScale and TyphoonAE are not (yet?) production-ready.